# For loop over a character vector and assigning a data frame to each element in the vector

Tags: r

I want to iterate along a character vector, read from a SAS file containing a string in the character vector as part of the path, then write this data frame into my database. Below is an example of my code that isn't working.

```
  for (j in c("table1", "table2")) {
    SAS_File_Path <- paste("C:/SAS_files/", j, ".sas7bdat", sep = "")
    if (file.exists(SAS_File_Path)){
        j <- read.sas7bdat(SAS_File_Path)
        sqlSave(ch, j, rownames = FALSE, append = TRUE)
    }
}
```

The for loop above seems to paste the the path together correctly making something like `C:/SAS_files/table1.sas7bdat` but then it gets assigned to a data frame named `j` rather than `table1`. I need the data frame to be named `table1` so I can append it to a pre-existing table in my data frame. Ultimately I want to iterate along a character vector and read a file into into a data frame assigned to the string in that element of the vector.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Doesn't `sqlSave` have a `tablename` argument? If so, problem solved.

Comment: It seems very strange that you are using `j` both as your loop index as well as a variable name for the data frame. Why not `dat <- read.sas7bdat(SAS_File_Path)`? Then using joran's suggestion, `sqlSave(ch, dat = dat, tablename = j, rownames = FALSE, append = TRUE)`

Comment: (...and the usual idiom for this general task in R is to create a named list up front and assign each data frame to the list in turn)

Comment: See [How to make a list of data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) for examples and reasons why.